# CSS3 create background-image = invalid property value

Tags: css, background

I'm trying to create a diagonally-striped background pattern with CSS3 gradients, but I can't seem to get it to work. This is the code I am using:

```
body {
background-color: gray;
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent, transparent 35px,    rgba(255,255,255,.5) 35px, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 70px);
}
```

It just displays a solid, gray background. When I inspect element, it shows that background-image is an invalid property value. I am coding on a mac, and have tested on Firefox 13.0.1 and Chrome v20.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Well, I don't have a proper answer, but this tool has been invaluable for me: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: I've been playing around with gradient editors, but I'm not trying to create a gradient background.. I'm trying to create a background pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your browser likely doesn't support the unprefixed property. Try using the vendor prefixes:

```
html, body { 
    min-height: 100% 
}
body {
    background-color: gray;
    background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient( 135deg, transparent, transparent 35px, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 35px, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 70px);
    background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient( 135deg, transparent, transparent 35px, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 35px, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 70px);
    background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient( 135deg, transparent, transparent 35px, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 35px, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 70px);
    background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient( 135deg, transparent, transparent 35px, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 35px, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 70px);
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient( 135deg, transparent, transparent 35px, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 35px, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 70px);
}​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fefhz/7/

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient#Browser_compatibility

Comment: What's puzzling is that the code is supposed to look something like what's found here: http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#diagonal-stripes. I was playing around with the prefixed properties as well and got the same results as in your jsfiddle. I was reading the documentation and tried to replace '0deg' with 'bottom right' and tweaked the parameters to follow the examples in the documentation, but it didn't seem to work. I'll keep playing around and see what happens!

Comment: @7ch5 The problem is the height of your body element. See my answer above.

Answer (score -1):

Any reason that is has to be in CSS3? Why not use a small image and repeat it? Could you save you a lot of headache simply using a generator: http://www.stripegenerator.com/

Comment: I'm hoping that once I understand CSS3 better, I can change the look of the background directly from the stylesheet instead of creating a new file from a generator every time I need to make a change. If I can't figure this out, I will definitely use a generator though, so thanks!